# Webform CiviCRM contribution "other amount"

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, webform-civicrm

I've setup a webform with CiviCRM integration that ties back to a Contribution page. This creates a "Contribution Amount" field in the form that I've populated with a number of user selectable options that have assigned dollar amounts. I'd also like for there to be an "other amounts" option that allows the donor to type in a custom amount, just like in the standard CiviCRM contribution page options. I don't see such an option in the Webform settings. Can anyone advise how this is accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to preserve a predefined values and let the donor the option of entering another amount, [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) Drupal module works nicely with Webform CiviCRM and payment amounts.

Comment: Nice, but can you improve your answer by saying that this works with Webform CiviCRM and payment amounts just to absolutely nail the question

Comment: @petednz-fuzion done!

Answer (score 0):

ON the civicrm tab, check the Contribution Amount field and read the field help and i think you will figure you need to set the widget to Number

> This amount will be in addition to any paid events and memberships.
>
> Once added to the webform, this field can be configured in a number of ways by changing its settings.
>
> Possible Widgets:
>
> Number (default): Allow the user to enter an amount, optionally constrained by min, max, and increments.
>
> Hidden: Set the amount without giving the user a choice.
>
> Select/Radios: Allow the user to choose from one of several options.
>
> MultiSelect/Checkboxes: Each choice the user selects will be added together.
>
> Grid: Configure multiple items and quantities.

Comment: This works if I only want a field for a user defined amount, but I want a list of options (radios) and a user defined amount.