# How to put 'Other Amount' field in price set radio choices?

Tags: civicontribute

We want our Civicontribute page to do this, but don't want to use the Simple Donate extension. Is there any way to natively support this in CiviCRM? FYI - the 'Other' field is hidden until you select the option.

Is this another case where Webform CiviCRM comes to the rescue? :)

Even better than what is pictured below would be an 'Other' field that when selected, let you type the amount directly in that box.

Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 4.7

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Drupal CiviCRM Webform integration you can achieve this feature with the [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) Drupal module.

See this question for more detail [Webform CiviCRM contribution “other amount”](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18788/webform-civicrm-contribution-other-amount/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an extension that would use JS and CSS to alter the screen as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the required without simple donate extension, by default in contribution page settings, in 'Amounts' section there should be a checkbox to allow other amounts, check that selection and save.

Now in contribution page user will have the option to enter any other amount. The field will show up after 'other amount' radio selection will be selected.

[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/hznlmk).

Hope this helps.